# connection to external server (mongodb server) fails from fargate container deployed using cdk

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-cdk-typescript

1. I created a simple node.js/express app and created docker image and successfully pushed it to aws ecr.
2. Next, I created a **cdk** project to deploy this container to **fargate** with **public application load balancer**. `ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`
3. Although the deployment cmd (`cdk deploy`) was successful, cluster page in aws console shows "No tasks running" and Services tab within the cluster shows red bar with "0/1 Tasks running" and Tasks tab within cluster shows tasks are getting created and stopped (every 1 or 2 min, a task is created and eventually stopped and a new one is created and this keeps on going forever)
4. Going inside a stopped task and its Log tab shows
   `ERROR: Connecting to MongoDB failed. Please check if MongoDB server is running at the correct host/port.`. This is the error message I have in my app when connection to mongodb fails when the server is initialized.
5. The DB credentials and connection url are valid (see below) and it runs in a separate EC2 instance with EIP and domain name. In fact, I can connect to the DB from my dev machine which is outside aws.
6. Also, just for trial, I created a stack manually through console by creating security groups (for load balancer and service), target group, application load balancer, listener (port 80 HTTP), cluster, task definition (with correct db credentials set in env var), service, etc., it's working without any issue.
7. All I want is to create similar stack using cdk (I don't want to manually create/maintain it)
8. Any clue on why connection to external server/db is failing from a fargate container would be very useful. I'm unable to compare the "cdk created cloudformation template" (that's not working) with the "manually created stack" (that's working) as there are too many items in the autogenerated template.

Here is the cdk code based on aws [sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/fargate-application-load-balanced-service/index.ts) code:

```
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "MyVpc", { maxAzs: 2 });
const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "MyCluster", { vpc });

const logDriver = ecs.LogDriver.awsLogs({ streamPrefix: "api-log" });
const ecrRepo = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, "app-ecr", "abcdef");
new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
  this, "FargateService", {
    assignPublicIp: true,
    cluster,
    desiredCount: 1,
    memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
    cpu: 512,
    taskImageOptions: {
      containerName: "api-container",
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromEcrRepository(ecrRepo),
      enableLogging: true,
      logDriver,
      environment: { MONGO_DB_URL: process.env.DB_URL as string }
    },
    publicLoadBalancer: true,
    loadBalancerName: "api-app-lb",
    serviceName: "api-service"
  }
);
```

Comment: mongodb server is running in a separate ec2 instance (without container) and I don't want/can't change.

Comment: BTW, I suspected the issue could be due to 2 security groups created by cdk. So, I manually changed inbound and outbound rules to allow any port from/to anywhere. It's not working and the tasks are getting created and stopped due to connection issue. Do I need to do anything after changing the security groups so that new value are used?

Comment: Are the ECS cluster and the EC2 database in the same VPC?

Comment: I would like to keep the code to a minimum so that I can leverage aws' best practices/patterns and default configurations.

Comment: @MarkB: The VPCs are different for the ecs cluster and ec2 database. Interestingly, the VPCs of manually created ecs cluster and ec2 database are same. This could be the reason. How to specify existing VPC in cdk api? Also, I'm connecting to db using dns name. Still, the VPC should be same?

Comment: changed ```const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, "MyVpc", { maxAzs: 2 });``` to ```const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "vpc", { vpcId: "vpc-1234...", availabilityZones: ["az1", "az2"] });```. Now `cdk synth` gives `Error: There are no 'Public' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types` error. Any idea on how to create a fargate cluster in an existing vpc is appreciated? (the same vpc where ec2 db server is running)

Comment: I tried the suggestion given in https://twitter.com/pahudnet/status/1406945727520022529/photo/1, but that didn't work, getting the same error. Setting tag with `Key: aws-cdk:subnet-type` and `Value: Public` for all subnets under vpc (ec2's vpc)

Comment: Still having issues with accessing external server from container created using cdk `ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`. Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a silly mistake! Instead of `MONGO_DB_URL` it should be `DB_URL` because that's what my node.js/express server in the container is using.